# Webdriver.io - Node.js Unexpected token import - Page Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io

Hello I have problem running my test scripts using Node.JS and Webdriver.io everything was working fine untill I tried to implement Page Object Pattern. On console output I receive error:

> ERROR: Unexpected token import
>
> user/Desktop/webdriverio-test/test/specs/first.js:2
>
> import GooglePage from '../pom/GooglePage';

Node version: v8.9.1

GooglePage.js:

```
class GooglePage{

get submitButton(){ return browser.element(`[name="btnK"]`);}

get searchField(){return browser.element('#lst-ib');}

open(){
    browser.open("http://google.com");
}

submit(){
    this.submitButton.click();
}

setValue(text){
    this.searchField.setValue(text);
}
}
export default new GooglePage();
```

And test script:

```
var assert = require('assert');
import GooglePage from '../pom/GooglePage';
 
describe('Visiting Google by PageObjectPattern',()=>{
 it('Open Google',()=>{
     GooglePage.open();
     GooglePage.setValue("asdasd")
     })
  })
```

Everything is almost the same as on: http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/pageobjects.html

Why it can't import my class to test script using import syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things to note:

1) Ensure that you are passing in the flag that [enables ESM support in Node 8.5+](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_enabling)

> Enabling#
>
> The --experimental-modules flag can be used to enable features for
>   loading ESM modules.
>
> Once this has been set, files ending with .mjs will be able to be
>   loaded as ES Modules.
>
> node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs

2) It appears that your ESM file's extension is ".js" and should instead be ".mjs", like so "GooglePage.mjs".

3) It also appears that you cannot import ESM from a CJS file and vs. So you'll either have to change your test spec to be a ".mjs" file, and import your dependencies like so:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import GooglePage from '../pom/GooglePage';
```

Or keep it as ".js" and require dependencies as CJS:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var GooglePage = require('../pom/GooglePage');

// Your module's content would be in GooglePage.default
```

Hope that helps!